# paramiko EOFError while trying to connect an ec2 device

Tags: python, ssh, amazon-ec2, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I'm using the Genymotion on demand aws instance, and trying to connect it from python. I would like to send adb commands to the instance from  python. There is a tutorial for connecting the instance from any computer here: https://www.genymotion.com/help/on-demand/tutorial/enable-disable-adb/

The ssh command used for creating ssh tunnel for the instance is:

```
ssh -i key.pem -NL 5555:localhost:5555 root@instance_ip
```

I tried to use the paramiko library, and the forward.py demo from their repo(https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py).

first, I tried to create the tunnel through the cli, and this is the what I entered for creating the ssh tunnel:

```
python forward.py <instance_ip> -r localhost:5555 -u root -p 5555 -K "path/to/mykey.pem"
```

The response was:

```
Connecting to ssh host <instance_ip>:22 ...
*** Failed to connect to <instance_ip>:22: EOFError()
```

I couldn't figure out what is the problem here.

Can someone help me here? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet to ssh to an EC2 instance from Python.

```
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(path/to/mykey.pem)
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect/ssh to an instance
try:
    client.connect(hostname=instance_ip, username="root", pkey=key)

    # Execute a command(cmd) after connecting/ssh to an instance
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
    print stdout.read()

    # close the client connection once the job is done
    client.close()
    break

except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Comment: I actually tried many snippets like this(and also this one). everytime it throws me the same "EOFError". I think that it might be a problem with my private key file, but I really don't know what is the problem.

Comment: For the code I posted, only reasons not to work could be 1) Wrong pem key 2) Wrong Instance IP 3) Wrong EC2 instance user name. Please check these 3. If that doesn't help, post your code here.                                                             Note: give full file path including pem file name. ex: key_path = os.path.join('license', 'file_name.pem')

Comment: And also to ensure your key and ip address are fine ssh from your linux machine and see whether connection is established.                                       ssh -i file_name.pem user_name@ip_address

Comment: I did exactly what you said(many times actually), but it still doesn't work.
the paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file line works fine, and i also saw  that the function _read_private_key in the pkey.py in paramiko package looks good. The ssh from my terminal also works.

Comment: Do you know about any other ways to check my pem file? 
By the way, Thank you very much!

Comment: You said "The ssh from my terminal also works".                                        Do you mean ssh to EC2 instance from your terminal works? (ssh -i file_name.pem user_name@ip_address). If that's the case your pem file is fine and even user name, ip addresses.